# Not able to post announcements with same title using createAnnouncements in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

My objective is to fetch emails from a particular account and post it on sites as announcements. I have accomplished this. However there is a unique scenario where an email with additional information will appear with the same subject (subject is the title of the post). I need to fetch this and post it as an announcement too. However createAnnouncements throws an error saying that post already exists. However I can manually post two posts with same title.

I have tried a numerous things like getAnnouncements and getAllDecedents but nothing served my purpose or is coming close to it.

Is there a way bu which I can delete the old post and create the new post Or is there a way I can post messages with same title using createAnnouncements? Any help in this regard will much appreciated.

I have included a potion of my code below.

```
      var pageTitlePattern = /^\[.*\] \[/;
      var pageTitleArray = pageTitlePattern.exec(messageSubject);
      var pageTitle = pageTitleArray[0].substr(1,pageTitleArray[0].length - 4);

      var messageIdPattern = /\] \[.*\]$/;
      var messageIdArray = messageIdPattern.exec(messageSubject);
      var messageId = messageIdArray[0].substr(3,messageIdArray[0].length - 4);
      var postBody = formatMessage(message, false) + "<br>" + "<font color=\"#ffffff\">" + messageId + "</font>";
      var newAccouncement = postPage.createAnnouncement(pageTitle, postBody);
      var files = message.getAttachments();
      for (var k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
        newAccouncement.addHostedAttachment(files[k]);
        cabinetPage.addHostedAttachment(files[k]);
      }
      message.markRead();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you manually create multiple announcement posts with the same name, the Sites UI automatically makes the path for the announcement unique by appending a hyphen and an integer.

For instance, if you create two posts with the title "TestPost", you will have these pages added to your site:

```
https://sites.google.com/site/--site-id--/announcements/testpost
https://sites.google.com/site/--site-id--/announcements/testpost-1
```

I suggest you have your script perform similarly.

```
...
var pageTitlePattern = /^\[.*\] \[/;
var pageTitleArray = pageTitlePattern.exec(messageSubject);
var pageTitle = pageTitleArray[0].substr(1,pageTitleArray[0].length - 4);

// Check if this pageTitle already used
var announcements = page.getAnnouncements({ 
                                         includeDrafts: false,
                                         includeDeleted: false,
                                         search: pageTitle });
// If other announcements have already used this pageTitle,
// make ours unique by appending a hyphen and unique number
if (announcements.length > 0) {
  pageTitle += '-' + announcements.length;
}
...
```

The `page.getAnnouncements()` search is case-insensitive, and finds all announcements with the string `pageTitle` anywhere in the title or text. This might be more inclusive than you want. In that case, an alternative is to take over creation of your announcement's page `name` by using [this variant of createAnnouncement()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page?hl=en#createAnnouncementsPage%28String,String,String%29).